# Universal Turing Machine algorithm

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, computer-architecture, turing-completeness

First, I learned this based on these facts:

1. Turing machine (*TM*) will be define with 7-tuple Notation, $M=\langle Q,G,b,S,d,q_0,F\rangle$.
2. Any computation rules that can use to simulate any possible *TM* is called Turing-Complete.
3. Universal *TM* (*UTM*) is TM that is Turing-Complete.

Then, the question begins:

- If we have 7-tuple Notation of any **U** that is *UTM*, Is there an algorithm to find initial tape content **P** that **U** to simulate any *TM* **T** with any **I** input(s)? If it exists, Does it based on each **U** or pattern of **U**? If it does, give me some example(s)? If it does, explain the algorithm?
- Since all possible computations can be done with *TM*, Is there an algorithm to make *TM* simulate any algorithm **P** written in any language? If it exists, give me some example(s)?
- If both questions above exist the algorithm, Why don't we just make a single *UTM* **U** and use it to program itself then do every possible computation?

Answer (score 1):

With regards too your first question I would take a different easier to understand route.
Firstly you should note that most programming languages are (theoretically) Turing-Complete (which implied that for a program written in some programming language like C or Python you could transform it into a TM or vice versa).

I'm sure that you heard of the concept ["interpreter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)). It's a program that takes a script as input and runs it (e.g. the python interpreter). You can probably write a simple interpreter yourself [(great tutorial)](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/).

Now notice that your interpreter could be converted to a TM which takes programs as inputs and runs them, thus you *could* construct a UTM, and the input would be e.g. a python script.

With regards to your second question: as I mentioned most programming languages used today are (theoretically) Turing-Complete meaning that you could transform any Turing-Machine too a program in this language. The straight forward approach, which works in most object oriented languages is just to model a Turing-Machine (using e.g. a string as tape and an int to remember where on the tape your head is and so on...[simple example](https://www.python-course.eu/turing_machine.php#:%7E:text=Implementation%20of%20a%20Turing%20machine,the%20entries%20of%20the%20tape.&text=of%20our%20class%20TuringMachine%20implementation.)).
Algorithms that convert one program from one language to another are called transpilers.

I think I don't fully understand your last question. Of course you could plug a UTM into itself. It's like writing a python interpreter in python. The "problem" is that simulation comes at a cost. Generally if you simulate a UTM on a UTM the complexity of some operations increases.

Comment: The last question states that If there is a UTM then why don't we design cpu/ram/... as a UTM. For example, a mechanic UTM.

Comment: CPUs are sort of UTMs (They have finite memory which makes them less powerful than TMs). You give your cpu a program in the form of a list of instructions and it executes the program on any given input. You can express a TM as a list of instructions thus a typical CPU is a UTM ( if we neglect the finite memory).